# Exploratory analysis and feature engineering for time till failure prediction using sensor data of engines

Tags: time-series, lstm, unsupervised-learning, feature-engineering, supervised-learning

I am trying to do some data exploration and analysis on a dataset of engine sensor readings. I would like to determine if the data I have is good enough to predict a time till failure and possibly classify the type of failure.

**Background:**

The data is collected at random time intervals of about 5 to 10 minutes in 1-minute bursts. Each 1-minute burst contains 4 groups of distinct sensors for about 15 seconds each. These groups are organized by sensors commonly used together for manual diagnosis by a technician. The idea is to hopefully be able to capture important relationships between these sensors and the 'degradation' over time. There are many engines that are missing data because of unreliable communication interfaces during collection. Another layer of complexity is that there is not a feature for defining the type of each engine. EX: Manufacture or different engine stats 
There are not a lot of data on engines with a failure as there are only 800 engines, in 8 possible classes of failures, out of the 20,000 engines.

I might have gotten ahead of myself, but here is what I have done so far:

- resampled the data into days by getting the min, max, mean, std, 25%, 50%, 75%
- graphed a correlation matrix
- graphed some sensor data to verify the data shows signs of 'degrading' over time
- ran some simple ML classifiers and regressors to get a baseline auc and accuracy
- used some unsupervised learning techniques to create new features
  EX: used dynamic time warping as a distance metric for DBscan clustering

Right now, I don't see much correlation between the engineered features and didn't get many good results with any supervised ML. I have not yet tried LSTMs or variations on the OneVsRest classifier, but from what I have read those are popular techniques for these types of problems.

Any ideas how to explore the data further?
Any ideas how to create new features, resample, or extract the relationships of the sensor of time series data?